# WPF: the right way to reuse resources in wpf

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have some storyboards defined in a `<Window.Resources>` tag in Xaml, and I wanna use them on a number of UIElement objects, so I think somehow I have to keep resetting the storyboard everything I retrieve it since it may have been used before, what's the right way to do this? Do I call `MyStoryBoard.clone()` everything I pull it out from the resources? Or should I call `MyStoryBoard.GetAsFrozen()`? Is there a better way to do this? What's the standard practice?

Comment: put them in a ResourceDictionary

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the [x:Shared](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970778.aspx) attribute to false, to prevent your resource being reused. This will create a new instance for each call of `{StaticResource MyStoryBoard}`.

```
<StoryBoard x:Key="MyStoryBoard" x:Shared="False" />
```